# C++ "expected a declaration"

Tags: c++, qt

I'm just getting started in C++ and already I have a problem. I'm trying to make a QFile (from QTCore) called brushInput. It's saying "expected a declaration". I've looked it up and it appears to occur from syntax issues but I don't see that in my code. Does it with and without the class.

```
#include <QtCore>

class Ink
{
    QFile *brushInput;

    brushInput = new QFile("x:\Development\InkPuppet\brush.raw");
};
```

Comment: please post the exact error message with line numbers.

Comment: When citing compilation issues, make sure to include the **exact** error message, including filename and line number. It should point you right to the error.

Comment: You don't put assignments inside class declarations, they belong inside function definitions.

Comment: The problem is likely with the included file.  You're probably not compiling it with the correct parameters.  Please post the command you used to compile the code.

Comment: @Barmar he said it happens with and without the class.

Comment: Please show your code that fails without the class.

Comment: @Barmar really?  it probably looks like `#include <QtCore>`

Comment: That IS the exact error, and it happens on the `brushInput = new QFile("x:\Development\InkPuppet\brush.raw");` line. I didn't use a command to compile the code, it hasn't even been compiled, it errors out soon as that line is typed. This is being done inside of QT Creator. I'm setting up a compiler now, but for the record I had this exact code inside my linux OS with a GCC compiler and the exact same thing happened.

Comment: as soon as that line is typed?  You need to be a LOT more specific with your question.  What is the error WITHOUT the class?

Comment: Folks, there's enough information in the question to diagnose the problem (though yes, an exact error message would have been nice). The assignment is a statement, and statements can appear only within function definitions, not at class scope.

Comment: @KeithThompson he explicitly said it happens without that line, so it's tough to see that we have enough information.

Comment: @xaxxon: It is **not** a problem with the include file because the error message clearly speaks about a specific problem: "expected a declaration". Having an assignment which isn't part of a declaration inside the class definition or at namespace scope is illegal.

Comment: You also have an error that will make the code fail *after* successful compilation (unless your compiler alerts you to this error). The character "\" cannot be used literally inside a string, you need to escape it with the usual C escape character -- which also happens to be "\".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an assignment in a class definition. You could have a default initialization in the class definition in C++11, though:

```
class Ink
{
    QFile* brushInput = new QFile("x:\\Development\\InkPuppet\\brush.raw"); 
};
```

However, normally I would expect that the initialization goes into a constructor:

```
class Ink
{
    QFile* brushInput;
public:
    Ink(): brushInput(new QFile("x:\\Development\\InkPuppet\\brush.raw")) {}
};
```

Comment: thanks, that did it -- just one more question -- how would i implement this code because it's giving the same error, `brushInput->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);` .. I've read up a lot on C++ but no one ever writes about the basic stuff..

Comment: @user1090427: what do you mean with "that did it ... its giving the same error"? Also `brushInput->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);` isn't an error. Note, however, that you need to duplicate your backslashes as a backslash is an escape character (I shall fix my answer, too).

Comment: due to your solution it's working now is what I meant. I was asking how to implement the following code: `brushInput->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);` sorry for any confusion

Comment: I assume it would go something like this: `Ink(): brushInput(open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {}`

Comment: @user1090427: I have no idea how to use `QFile`. If you need to call `open()` on the object, you'd do it in the body of the constructor as you mentioned in your comment: `brushInput->open(...);` (you might not need to allocate the `QFile` on the heap but, again, I don't know about `QFile`)

Answer (score 1):

You can't make assignments inside classes, only initializations. Therefore, use the member-initializer list of your class:

```
class Ink
{
    QFile *brushInput;
public:
    Ink() : brushInput(new QFile("x:\Development\InkPuppet\brush.raw"));
};
```

Comment: how does this address the part of the question that states it happens without the class?  `Does it with and without the class.`

Comment: @xaxxon He hasn't given us enough information as of yet to address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
brushInput = new QFile("x:\Development\InkPuppet\brush.raw");
```

is a statement. Statements (other than declarations) can appear only inside function definitions, not at class or file scope.

Putting the statement inside a function definition (perhaps a constructor) determines when the statement will be executed. If you're thinking it should be executed when the object is created -- well, that's what constructors are for.

Comment: how does this address the comment that it happens without the class?  `Does it with and without the class.`

Comment: @xaxxon Since he hasn't shown the code without the class, we can't really address that case. All we can do is work with what we see.

Comment: Without the surrounding `class`, it would be at file scope, and therefore still illegal.

Comment: @xaxxon: Even outside the class statements are prohibited unless they happen to be declarations. Something of the form `x = value;` is _not_ a declaration but a statement. Statements, in general, are only permitted inside function bodies.

Answer (score 0):

As you are clearly new to C++, here a number of things to know to get started:

1. In C++ there are 2 kind of source files: header files (.h) and source files (.cpp).
   Everything in C++ must be both declared and implemented. These are two different things.
   The general rule is that the declarations go into the header file, the implementations go into the .cpp file.

   In your case:

   ```
   //ink.h file
   #ifndef INK_H    //this avoids multiple inclusion
   #define INK_H
   #include <QtCore>

   class QFile;  //let the compiler know the QFile is defined elsewhere

   class Ink
   {
       public:     //as a rule of thumb,
                   //always declare the visibility of methods and member variables
           Ink();  //constructor
           ~Ink(); //it is a good practice to always define a destructor

       private:
           QFile *brushInput;
   };
   #endif

   //.cpp file
   #include "ink.h"

   //implementation of the constructor
   Ink::Ink() :
       brushInput(new QFile("x:/Development/InkPuppet/brush.raw");  //you can use forward slashes; Qt will convert to the native path separators
   {}
   ```
2. Avoid implementations in header file
   As a second rule, avoid implementations in the header file, certainly of constructors and destructors.
   Implementations of methods in the header files are known as inline methods (and they have to be marked like that).  As a start, avoid them, and try to implement everything in the .cpp file. When you are more familiar with C++, you can start using the 'more advanced' things.